# How to extract between special characters in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a sentence: `db.COLLECTION_NAME.insert(document)`

1. I need to extract whatever's between `db.` and `.insert`, which in the example is `COLLECTION_NAME`.
2. And Anything between the `()` which in the example is `document`.

I tried:

```
 document="${cmd#db*insert(}"
```

for `document`, but it gets `document)` and will crash if document has special characters

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Relevant info](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo "db.COLLECTION_NAME.insert(document)" | awk -F'[.()]' '{print $2,$4}'
```

will give

```
COLLECTION_NAME document
```

You can assign these to variables with `read`

```
read a b < <(echo "db.COLLECTION_NAME.insert(document)" | awk -F'[.()]' '{print $2,$4}');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have a project to use mongodb commands in bash script. can i take the output of awk in variables?

Comment: $4 match only one word. Is there a possibilty to match whatever the strings or special characters between ( )?

Comment: As long as there are no `FS` chars (period or open/close parans) it's considered one token.  If so please post a representative sample.

Comment: I just sent $4 to another script and read it as a one argument, but now it fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can do it using brace expansion in two steps:

```
str='db.COLLECTION_NAME.insert(document)'
temp=${str/db./}
str=${temp/.insert*/}
echo $str
COLLECTION_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

# set x to a "typical" input value
x='db.COLLECTION_NAME.insert(document)'

# print it out, just so you see it
echo "x == ${x}"

if [[ "${x}" =~ ^db\.(.*)\.insert.* ]]; then
    # we have a match
    ans="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    # print the substring that matches the pattern
    echo "answer == ${ans}"
else
    # sorry no match
    echo "no match"
fi
```

Comment: This bash code uses the =~ operator to do a regular expression pattern match. The "builtin" array BASH_REMATCH contains the matches based on the regex and the input string.

Comment: Note, I used bash 4x. The =~ operator has been in bash for a while, but you might want to double check. Some shops are into deep backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using BASH's match operator:

```
regex='db[.](.*)[.]insert.*'
str='db.COLLECTION_NAME.insert(document)'
if [[ $str =~ $regex ]]; then 
   result=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
echo $result
COLLECTION_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you, @accdias, for confirming my answer above.

Comment: Sorry for double it. Yours wasn't post when I started writing mine. Same idea though. :-)

Comment: Hey, @accdias, that can happen, can't it (:-). All good. I appreciated your take on the problem as well. -d